# Google GMail API w G Suite - Can I insert directly a message into a gmail user mailbox?

Tags: gmail-api

In my project , the Contact Request Form is sent to an HTTP Firebase function ( Google Cloud Function wrapper...) the received data should be sent to a gmail user contact@mydomain.org (G Suite account)
( I am trying NOT to use another service like SendGrid... )

Currently I send the message with gmail.users.messages.send() , obviously GMail API is overwriting the From: original sender email with Googlea account admin email...

I tried to run before a gmail.users.settings.sendAs.create() to add the original from: email address, but in this case I need also to setup an smtpMsa server to be used as a relay ...

Is there anyway to BUILD a mail message from the data received ( from: msg_text: ) and INSERT IT DIRECTLY into my contact@mydomain.org gmail box to 'simulate' a received message with the correct information ? or should it be sent only by an smtp server ?

**UPDATE**

I can use  users.message.import() ... 
but I get an error when if I import into another email address ( contact@ ) than the account admin ...

```
{"infos":"Delegation denied for admin@mydomain.org"}
```

THIS WORKS
         return gmail.users.messages.import({
        userId: config_key.admin_email,
        resource: {
          raw: encodedMessage
        }
      });

THIS DON't WORK

```
 return gmail.users.messages.import({
    userId: config_key.contact_email,
    resource: {
      raw: encodedMessage
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**YES WE CAN !**

I succeeded finally ... inserting directly a message into my Google Suite email address .. and the from: address is actually the original contact form sender email address !

```
function gMailInserMessage (sender_name, sender_email, msg_text) {

  // Create a new JWT client using the key file downloaded from the Google Developer Console
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    postoffice_key.client_email,  // service account with Domain-Wide delagation of Authority
    null,
    postoffice_key.private_key,
    _.values(config_key.scopes.postoffice),
    config_key.admin_email // subject (or sub) impersonated user
  );

  return jwtClient.authorize().then(tokens => {
      // Obtain a new gmail client, making sure we pass along the auth client
      const gmail = google.gmail({
        version: 'v1',
        auth: jwtClient
       });

       // Base64-encode the mail and make it URL-safe 
       // (replace all "+" with "-" and all "/" with "_")
       var encodedMessage = btoa([
        'From: ' + sender_email + '\r\n',
        'To: ' + config_key.admin_email + '\r\n',
        'Subject: Contact\r\n\r\n',
        msg_text
      ].join("")).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

      //Make an authorized request to insert a User Messages
      return gmail.users.messages.insert({
        userId: 'me',  // impersonated authorized user
        resource: {
          raw: encodedMessage
        }
      });
  }).then(res => res.data);
}
```

the response is :

```
{"status":200,"infos": 
{"id":"1639b41c26584963","threadId":"1639b41c26584963"}}
```